# Problem with user input in my batch file

Tags: batch-file, user-input, if-statement

here is the portion of code giving me trouble:

```
IF EXIST TH_BUILD_* (
ECHO A current build of Test Harness exists.
set /p delBuild=Delete preexisting build [y/n]?: 
if "%delBuild%"=="y" (GOTO deleteandcontinue) else ( EXIT)
)
```

For some reason, no matter the input, the batch file exits. Why is this happening (deleteandcontinue is never reached)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using delayed expansion when testing `delBuild`:

```
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

IF EXIST TH_BUILD_* (
    ECHO A current build of Test Harness exists.
    set /p delBuild=Delete preexisting build [y/n]?: 
    if "!delBuild!"=="y" (
        GOTO deleteandcontinue
    ) else (
        exit
    )
)

:deleteandcontinue
@echo At deleteandcontinue
```

`%var%` variables are expanded when the command is read. The set of commands between the parens are treated as a single command, so `delBuild` doesn't exist when you go to test. With the delayed expansion, the variables are expanded when the command is executed, so at the time of the test, `delBuild` has a value.