# How to read input from console in a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

How do I read input from the console in a batch file? What I am trying to achieve is the functionality of scanf in C. How can I do the same in a batch file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem with user input in my batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/916413/problem-with-user-input-in-my-batch-file)

Comment: @ Raymond : Nope, question is to read multiple characters as a string from keyboard into a variable.

Comment: The command `set /p` reads whatever the user types, whether it be one letter or multiple.

Answer (score 174, accepted):

The code snippet in the linked proposed duplicate reads user input.

```
ECHO A current build of Test Harness exists.
set /p delBuild=Delete preexisting build [y/n]?:
```

The user can type as many letters as they want, and it will go into the delBuild variable.

Comment: Note: you can use the user input with `%delBuild%`

Comment: Have to notice that `echo !delBuild!` will give you a more reliably output on execution when `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` enabled

Answer (score 37):

If you're just quickly looking to keep a cmd instance open instead of exiting immediately, simply doing the following is enough

```
set /p asd="Hit enter to continue"
```

at the end of your script and it'll keep the window open.

Note that this'll set `asd` as an environment variable, and can be replaced with anything else.

Comment: for this purpose, someone invented the `pause` command. Also it's `set /p`, not `set \p`.

Comment: "As everyone is saying", implies that the answer is already given, so another one without more informatiion is needless

Comment: @jeb you're right. my issue was that they included variables and echo, while I didn't need any of that. It took me a minute or two to parse their answers, as I've got no batch experience. I believe my answer satisfies the bare minimum answer suited for my needs.

Comment: @Stephan thanks dude, on both counts. I was looking for a way to keep the cmd instance for exiting after a script had completed, simply pausing for X time wasn't enough.

Comment: @ArslanAhmad  I just tested, it still works from `cmd`, but not Powershell. Make sure you're using the right thing.

Comment: For anyone testing this example, have in mind that the `temp` environment setting usually points to the temporary folder, so doing this **overwrites** your setting. Fortunately, if you happen to run this in a cmd window, it only affects that instance and after running `exit` the damage is lost. You can check your current value by executing `set temp`.

Answer (score 26):

In addition to the existing answer it is possible to set a default option as follows:

```
echo off
ECHO A current build of Test Harness exists.
set delBuild=n
set /p delBuild=Delete preexisting build [y/n] (default - %delBuild%)?:
```

This allows users to simply hit "Enter" if they want to enter the default.