# Multiple choices menu on batch file?

Tags: batch-file

Hi I want to make a batch file menu, that asks 'Select app you want to install?' for example

1. App1
2. App2
3. App3
4. App4
5. App5
6. ALL Apps

Select what app:_

What I want is, for example I want to install App2, App3, and App5, so I can type on by App ID's 'Select what app:2,3,5' . And when user Select option 6, it will install all Applications!

I know this is possible on bash scripting, but Im not sure on batch scripting?

An example of batch menu is http://mintywhite.com/software-reviews/productivity-software/create-multiple-choice-menu-batchfile/

Comment: this question would be more likely to receive a good answer if you showed the work you've put into your bash script so far.

Comment: possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24972506/2152082)

Answer (score 10):

### Answer

This will do what you want.  Let me know if you have any questions.  All you have to do is follow the two steps listed in the script.

### Script

```
:: Hide Command and Set Scope
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions

:: Customize Window
title My Menu

:: Menu Options
:: Specify as many as you want, but they must be sequential from 1 with no gaps
:: Step 1. List the Application Names
set "App[1]=One"
set "App[2]=Two"
set "App[3]=Three"
set "App[4]=Four"
set "App[5]=Five"
set "App[6]=All Apps"

:: Display the Menu
set "Message="
:Menu
cls
echo.%Message%
echo.
echo.  Menu Title
echo.
set "x=0"
:MenuLoop
set /a "x+=1"
if defined App[%x%] (
    call echo   %x%. %%App[%x%]%%
    goto MenuLoop
)
echo.

:: Prompt User for Choice
:Prompt
set "Input="
set /p "Input=Select what app:"

:: Validate Input [Remove Special Characters]
if not defined Input goto Prompt
set "Input=%Input:"=%"
set "Input=%Input:^=%"
set "Input=%Input:<=%"
set "Input=%Input:>=%"
set "Input=%Input:&=%"
set "Input=%Input:|=%"
set "Input=%Input:(=%"
set "Input=%Input:)=%"
:: Equals are not allowed in variable names
set "Input=%Input:^==%"
call :Validate %Input%

:: Process Input
call :Process %Input%
goto End


:Validate
set "Next=%2"
if not defined App[%1] (
    set "Message=Invalid Input: %1"
    goto Menu
)
if defined Next shift & goto Validate
goto :eof


:Process
set "Next=%2"
call set "App=%%App[%1]%%"

:: Run Installations
:: Specify all of the installations for each app.
:: Step 2. Match on the application names and perform the installation for each
if "%App%" EQU "One" echo Run Install for App One here
if "%App%" EQU "Two" echo Run Install for App Two here
if "%App%" EQU "Three" echo Run Install for App Three here
if "%App%" EQU "Four" echo Run Install for App Four here
if "%App%" EQU "Five" echo Run Install for App Five here
if "%App%" EQU "All Apps" (
    echo Run Install for All Apps here
)

:: Prevent the command from being processed twice if listed twice.
set "App[%1]="
if defined Next shift & goto Process
goto :eof


:End
endlocal
pause >nul
```

Comment: I'm presented with the menu and after selecting one, the "app installs" and then the batch file closes out. I'd expect the menu to be displayed again so I could select the other "apps" to install.

Answer (score 5):

you may use choice.exe  see here : http://ss64.com/nt/choice.html

Comment: Excellent answer, thanks @Kayasax, that worked perfectly for my DOS menus.

Comment: Example from the link http://ss64.com/nt/choice.html cited in the answer ... `CHOICE /C CH /M Select [C] CD or [H] Hard drive`... 
Prof101 below has another example.

Answer (score 5):

You want to use `set /p`  Example below:

```
echo What would you like to install?
echo 1 - App1
echo 2 - App2

set /p whatapp=

if %whatapp%==1 (
    codetoinstallapp1
) else if %whatapp%==2 (
    codetoinstallapp2
) else (
    echo invalid choice
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a trick I learned:

```bat
echo.1) first choice
echo.2) second choice
echo.3) third choice
echo.4) fourth choice

:: the choice command

set pass=
choice /c 1234 /n /m "Choose a task"
set pass=%errorlevel%

::the choices

if errorlevel 1 set goto=1
if errorlevel 2 set goto=2
if errorlevel 3 set goto=3
if errorlevel 4 set goto=4
goto %goto%
```

While I use only 1-4 it would be very easy to add more possible choices.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
:menu
cls
echo.
echo Select the case color you want to create:
echo ==========================================
echo.
echo App 1
echo App 2
echo App 3
echo App 4
echo.
echo ==========================================
echo Please answer Y/N to the following:

set /p App1= Install App 1?
set /p App2= Install App 2?
set /p App3= Install App 3?
set /p App4= Install App 4?

if /I "%App1%" EQU "Y" goto :Option-1
if /I "%App1%" EQU "N" goto :1
:1
if /I "%App2%" EQU "Y" goto :Option-2
if /I "%App2%" EQU "N" goto :2
:2
if /I "%App3%" EQU "Y" goto :Option-3
if /I "%App3%" EQU "N" goto :3
:3
if /I "%App4%" EQU "Y" goto :Option-4
if /I "%App4%" EQU "N" goto :End



:Option-1
App 1 Loc.
goto 1
:Option-2
App 2 Loc.
goto 2
:Option-3
App 3 Loc.
goto 2
:Option-4
App 4 Loc.
:End

Exit
```

Answer (score 1):

Menu with analog of checkbox.

```
@echo off

set size=3

::preset
set chbox2=x


:prepare
for /L %%i in (0,1,%size%) do (
    if defined chbox%%i (
        set st%%i=Y
    ) else (
        set chbox%%i= 
    )
)


:menu
cls
echo.
echo  1. [%chbox1%]  name_1:
echo.
echo  2. [%chbox2%]  name_2:
echo.
echo  3. [%chbox3%]  name_3:
echo.
echo.
echo.


choice /C 1234567890qa /N /M "Select [1-9] >> [a]pply or [q]uit:"
echo.
set inp=%errorlevel%

if %inp%==11 (
    exit
)
if %inp%==12 (
    call :apply
)

::switch
if defined st%inp% (
    set st%inp%=
    set chbox%inp%= 
) else (
    set st%inp%=Y
    set chbox%inp%=X
)
goto :menu


:apply
for /L %%i in (0,1,%size%) do (
    if defined st%%i (
        call :st%%i
        echo.
    )
)
echo.
pause
goto :menu




:st1
echo First Command
goto :eof


:st2
echo Second Command
goto :eof


:st3
echo Third Command
goto :eof
```

You can set lines checked as defaults under :preset label.

Comment: I like this approach, it's easy to follow but is limited to 9 options, right?

Comment: @HPWD, You can bind all symbols which valid for "choice" command.

Comment: I don't know how to bind in a command prompt. :(

Answer (score 0):

A batch file is a list of command prompt commands. The following code prints to the terminal:

```
echo whateveryouwant
```

print your menu using these echo statements in a batch file.

Getting user input can be found here: [How to read input from console in a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7879791/how-to-read-input-from-console-in-a-batch-file)

The installing of applications is a little more complex - you need to know the requirements of your apps and where files should be moved - that should be simple, as well; use `move` on the appropriate files in the appropriate place.

Comment: I dont know If you understand my question !Check this out http://mintywhite.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/batch-menu.png and I want to for example on 'Type option' 1,3,4 <--- Multiple choices !

Comment: I already have all applications ready, Im using custom .exe and .msi applications so I can Install on Silent Mode, so what i want an answer, still I didnt get it !

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a batch script menu I'm using:

```
@echo off
setlocal
:begin
cls
echo [LOCAL ACCOUNTS REMOTE ADMIN] --------------------------------------
echo   1 -- List local accounts on a remote machine
echo   2 -- Create a local account on a remote machine
echo   3 -- Change a local account password on a remote machine
echo   4 -- Delete a local account on a remote machine
echo;
echo   5 -- exit
echo;
set /P rmFunc="Enter a choice: "
echo --------------------------------------------------------------------
for %%I in (1 2 3 4 5 x) do if #%rmFunc%==#%%I goto run%%I
goto begin

:run1
rem list local accounts code
goto begin

:run2
rem create local account code
goto begin

rem and so on, until...

:run5
:run9
:run99
:runx
endlocal
goto :EOF
```

The most relevant bits are the `set /p` line and the `for...in` lines.  The `for...in` line basically compares the choice entered with every menu item number, and if match, `goto run#`; otherwise start over from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I saw that none of the above answers completely answered his/her question. One feature that they have left out is selecting all the software it installs in one go (so to speak).

So I made this off the top of my head (extremely sorry if there is something wrong with it, I'll edit it if there is).

```
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

echo What would you like to install?
::Put your options here, preferably numbered.
set /p op=Type the numbers of the software you want to install (separated by commas with no spaces. E.g: 1,3,2): 

for /f "delims=, tokens=1-5" %%i in ("op") do (
set i=%%i
set j=%%j
set k=%%k
set l=%%l
set m=%%m
)
if %i%X neq X set last=1b & goto %i%
:1b
if %j%X neq X set last=2b & goto %j%
:2b
if %k%X neq X set last=3b & goto %k%
:3b
if %l%X neq X set last=4b & goto %l%
:4b
if %m%X neq X set last=%m% & goto %m%
goto next

:1
::Put the code for doing the first option here
goto %last%
:2
::Put the code for doing the second option here
goto %last%
:3
::Put the code for doing the third option here
goto %last%
:4
::Put the code for doing the fourth option here
goto %last%
:5
::Put the code for doing the fifth option here
goto %last%
```

:next
::Put some more stuff here...

So that was a bit excessive. Feel free to change some things around and such.

What the code is doing is getting the user input (such as if you put in "1,3,4"), putting each number into its own variable, checking if that variable is empty, and if it isn't, sending you to code that does whatever the option was. It does this a few times until all the variables have been assessed.

Comment: I was never prompted to enter a value.

Answer (score 0):

This is a proposed analysis for improvement on David Ruhmann's code relating to the "Validate Input" section above:

Testing the menu for special characters works a charm except for the following characters "^&<". When each are submitted for input the program closes.

```
set "Input=%Input:"=%"
set "Input=%Input:^^=%"
set "Input=%Input:>=%"
set "Input=%Input:<=%"
set "Input=%Input:^&=%"
set "Input=%Input:|=%"
set "Input=%Input:(=%"
set "Input=%Input:)=%"
:: Equals are not allowed in variable names
set "Input=%Input:^==%"
```

Escaping the ^ and & works, but something very peculiar going on with the parsing of "<" and ">" (escaping these doesn't appear to work). If we reverse the order of the two statements as in the above amendment we find "<" works, but now ">" doesn't.

However, shifting the second statement with "<" down thus, both redirection characters work but now ")" doesn't!!

```
set "Input=%Input:"=%"
set "Input=%Input:^^=%"
set "Input=%Input:>=%"
set "Input=%Input:^&=%"
set "Input=%Input:|=%"
set "Input=%Input:(=%"
set "Input=%Input:)=%"
set "Input=%Input:<=%"
:: Equals are not allowed in variable names
set "Input=%Input:^==%"
```

Another great tutorial for batch menus is found [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/78083-batch-files-create-menu-execute-commands.html).

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this

```
@echo off
:a
echo Welcome to a casual log-in (you are a idiot)

echo.

pause


echo ÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄ

set /p c=Email:

echo ÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄ

set /p u=Password:

echo ÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄ

msg * Welcome %c%.

goto a
```

Answer (score 0):

There is actually an extremely easy way to do this.

```
@echo off
echo Which app do you want to install?
echo [APP 1]
echo [APP 2]
echo [APP 3]
echo.
echo Type 1, 2, or 3.
set /p "AppInstaller=>"
if %AppInstaller%==1 goto 1
if %AppInstaller%==2 goto 2
if %AppInstaller%==3 goto 3
:1
[INSTALL CODE]
:2
[INSTALL CODE]
:3
[INSTALL CODE]
```

The menu, when coded like this, will look like this:

```
Which app do you want to install?
[APP 1]
[APP 2]
[APP 3]

Type 1, 2, or 3.
>_
```

The code sets the variable AppInstaller to 1, 2, or 3. The file determines this and redirects you to an installer for each one.

Comment: please read the question again. OP wants to input something like `2,3,5` (choosing more than one at the same time)

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly easy code that I use a lot in multiple choice games:

```
@echo off
color 0a
cls
:download
echo App 1
echo App 2
echo App 3
echo App 4
echo App 5
echo All Apps
echo 
echo Select What App (1, 2, 3, ect.):
set /p apps=

if %apps%==1 goto 1
if %apps%==1 goto 2
if %apps%==1 goto 3
if %apps%==1 goto 4
if %apps%==1 goto 5
if %apps%==1 goto all

:1
(Your Code Here)
:2
(Your Code Here)
:3
(Your Code Here)
:4
(Your Code Here)
:5
(Your Code Here)
:all
(Your Code Here)
```