# How to write a batch file with offering some options for user?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I think I have what I want (described below), thank you so much again, but please two more options... When I want to add in sub menu two next options for example "B" like go on Begin and "E" like Exit. It will be like:

Hello I am Zedd, please choose one app bellow:

1. Notepad
2. Calc
3. Other

When I touch "3" like other I will get next menu:

1. FFox
2. IE
3. or B. Go Back
4. or E. Exit

How can I do this? And can I use just number 0-9 or I can use also 10,11 etc.?

Examople of code maybe like this?

```
@echo off  
:begin  
echo.  
echo Hello, I'm Zedd...  
echo.  
echo Choose:
echo.  
echo 1. Notepad  
echo 2. Calc  
echo 3. Other  
echo.  
choice /c 123  
if %errorlevel%==1 goto :Notepad  
if %errorlevel%==2 goto :Calc 
if %errorlevel%==3 goto :Other

:Notepad  
start notepad.exe  
goto :eof 

:Calc  
start calc.exe  
goto :eof 

:Other  
echo.  
echo Choose:  
echo.  
echo 1. FFox  
echo 2. IE  
echo 3 or B. Back
echo 4 or E. Exit  
echo.  
choice /c 1234(maybe 12be if I can use also b and e, or I can use 3,4... is possible here use 10,11,12 etc.?)    
if %errorlevel%==1 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"  
if %errorlevel%==2 "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"  
if %errorlevel%==3 goto :begin?  
if %errorlevel%==4 exit?  
goto :other (I want to stay in other for choosing next apps but I want to be able to go back or exit)
```

Also, can I do it with note, so when I choose FFox there will be message "You choosed FFox" etc.?

Hope I described it clearly, if you can help me, I will be happy, thank you!

---

Could you please advise me on how to write **commands in CMD** using a batch file that would include different options and actions?

I've researched a nice description of the functions I can use, but I'm not able to put together them functionally.

Here's an example of the output message that I want when my batch file runs on Windows:

**I need to do batch, for example "test.bat"**

I think this is the easiest way. In this batch I want to have some text and some choices. For example bellow:

```
Hello, I am Zedd, here is few options for you, please choose one. 

1. Run notepad.exe 
2. Other apps
```

After entering number 1, Notepad is opened. After entering number 2, more options should be displayed:

```
1. Firefox
2. More informations
   etc.
```

I need to run this batch file on Windows.

What is best way how to do this?

It can be full-screen or just within a window.

Also I need open apps or pictures, etc.

Comment: Is it _actual_ MS-DOS or just the cmd window? Are you literally running MS-DOS 6 (or whatever version is on the legacy system you are using)? Because there is actually a **huge** difference between the two and some commands for one won't work on the other.

Comment: the question states "my batch file runs on Windows".

Comment: Just cmd windows, which possibilities are here?
Yes, you are right, so sorry about this, I'll correct it if possible...

Comment: fullscreen? not with batch. Open program or App? yes (for example just `notepad.exe`). Using options? yes - if the program or app supports them. Hard to help you, if you don't state a specific problem.

Comment: Ok, so all what I need is possible, but I don't know how to do it... so I try to describe it again.

I need to do batch, for example "test.bat" <- I think this is the eaisiest way.
In this bath I want to have some text and some choices... for basic example:

Hello, I am Zedd, here is few options for you, please choose one.

1. Run notepad.exe
2. Other apps

After touch number 1 is opened notepad.
After touch number 2 we can see next options

1. Firefox
2. More informations

Etc. etc., I hope now is more clear what I need. Sorry again about this and thank you!

Comment: yes, save it as "test.bat" and run it. Edited my answer to include a second level of choices.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple choices menu on batch file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14529246/multiple-choices-menu-on-batch-file)

Comment: I think this was solved, now I have few more questions, can you help me please? Thank you so much!

Comment: @Zedd see my edited answer (in the future please don't change your question, ask a new question instead; maybe with a reference to this one)

Comment: @Stephan thank you so much for your BIG help, I really appreciate it. I understand and next time will do new question, sorry for that. But now please finish this, I asked one more thing in comment bellow, under you answer.

Answer (score 1):

(**Edited** to show the usage of a second level of choices)

just a combination of `echo` and `choice` commands:

```
@echo off
:begin
echo Hello, I am Zedd, here is few options for you, please choose one. 
echo 1. Run notepad.exe 
echo 2. Other apps
choice /c 12
if %errorlevel%==1 goto :notepad
if %errorlevel%==2 goto :other    
:notepad
echo you choosed Notepad.
start notepad.exe
goto :eof

:other
echo 1. Mozilla Firefox
echo 2. Microsoft Internet Explorer
echo 3. MyBatchFile
echo B. back to main menue
echo E. exit
choice /c 123B
if %errorlevel%==1 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
if %errorlevel%==2 "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
if %errorlevel%==3 (
  echo you choosed MyBatchFile
  call "c:\test\mybatch.bat"
  goto :begin
)
if %errorlevel%==4 (
  echo you entered "B" to go back to main menue
  goto :begin
)
if %errorlevel%==5 (
  echo bye bye...
  exit /b
)
goto :other
```

You can add the `/n` parameter to `choice` to supress `[1,2]?`

**EDIT** 02-sep (please don't change your question, this may invalidate already existing answers; ask a new question instead, referencing this old question)

*"How can I do this? And can I use just number 0-9 or I can use also 10,11 etc.?"*

No. `choice` reacts on keypresses, not on input strings, so only single numbers *or letters*. Although `3 or B. Back` is possible: `choice /c 123b4e` will return errorlevel 1 for `1`, 2 for `2`, 3 for `3`, 4 for `b` or `B`, 5 for `4`, 6 for `e` or `E`. (read `choice /?` for details). Then

```
...
if %errorlevel%==3 goto :back   REM this was a "3"
if %errorlevel%==4 goto :back   REM this was a "B"
...
```

*"Also, can I do it with note, so when I choose FFox there will be message "You choosed FFox" etc.?"*

Yes. Just add an `echo` after each label (see example above with the `:notepad` label.

Comment: If he's literally running MS-DOS, there is no choice option. (Admittedly, he's likely not, but there's still room for ambiguity right now.)

Comment: Thank you for answer, its near, but still not what I need to do.

Comment: so, what do you need? Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31990450/edit) your question

Comment: Thank you so much for edition Stephan, if I add @ on begin, its hide "ways" and other tags, not it lookis like it is what I was looking for. Thank you again, If I will have some issues, I ask you again, if possible.

Comment: just add `@echo off` as the first line. That will suppress command repetition for all lines.

Comment: Stephan, thank you again, I still have problem with "Exit" and "go to Begin", its not working for me. Also I need to add "message" to %errorlevel% if possible.
My example
'echo.
choice /c 12be
if %errorlevel%==1 \\t1\t1\t.bat echo you chosed t1
if %errorlevel%==2 \\t2\t2\t2.bat echo you chosed t2
if %errorlevel%==b goto begin
if %errorlevel%==e exit
goto :Other'

I need to stay in selection for "other" because I choose to run 1 after 2 and after I can go back or exit, so its why is on end "goto :Other", but how can I do Exit/Close or goto :begin if this is on end? Also how about echo msg here?

Comment: I implemented your requests (in different ways - not a good programming behaviour - to show you different possibilities). Keep in mind: if you just start another batchfile with `c:\t1\t1\t1.bat`, it will never return. Use `call` to continue after `t1` is finished..

Comment: @Stephan, thank you so much for all, now is all working how I need, you are really good guy, big up for you!

Comment: the best "big up" would be to accept the answer. This will also tell everyone, this question has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it could be possible to do that in plain batch commands. I would suggest, though, use a language like C++ or C, to do that...but if you must use batch, [here are a lot of commands](http://ss64.com/nt/) that you can play with.

Comment: You would be surprised, [what's possible](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4741), using plain batch...

Comment: Thank you all for your time and help. I checked commands and md-dos examples, but I still can't find what I want. Also, I need to see it on example, because it is lot of years when I did similar thing at last and now I am lost. Thank you for understanding.