# How to make a custom "Press any key to continue" message in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

For an example "Press any key to return to command prompt"

what do I even put here lol.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29158548/288568

Comment: You can output any custom message using the echo command. For a list of cmd commands, See: https://ss64.com/nt/

Answer (score 0):

There can be used in the batch file the command line:

```
set /P "=Press any key to return to command prompt... " <nul & pause >nul & echo(
```

The caret is blinking in this case on same line as the prompt and not on the next line as it is the case on using:

```
echo Press any key to return to command prompt...
pause >nul
```

But in most cases can be simply used just `pause` to halt the batch file execution until the user pressed a key which is often not necessary on user executed the batch file from within a command prompt window.

There can be used the following command line to halt the batch file execution only if `cmd.exe` was started with option `/c` as first argument as done when double clicking on a batch file.

```
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion & for /F "tokens=1,2" %%G in ("!CMDCMDLINE!") do endlocal & if /I "%%~nG" == "cmd" if /I "%%~H" == "/c" pause
```

This command line does not run `pause` if the batch file is executed from within an opened command prompt window by a user who typed the batch file name and pressed <kbd>RETURN</kbd> or <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to execute it. It is often annoying for a user of a batch file starting it from within a command prompt window to press a key to end its execution.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `cmd /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `help` ... outputs an incomplete list of [Windows commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands) with a brief description
- `pause /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

See also:

- [A-Z index of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564)
- Microsoft documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10))
- DosTips forum topic: [ECHO. FAILS to give text or blank line - Instead use ECHO/](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=774)