# Cannot take user input in batch file while in if statement

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, user-input

I want to get input from user in a batch file but while it works fine when I am outside of if statement, when I get inside it doesn't get user's input.

```
@echo off

set /p flag=Enter letter 'y': 

echo %flag%

if %flag% == y (
    set /p flag2=Enter random string:

    echo flag2: %flag2%
)

pause
```

In the above example after I enter 'y' for the first prompt, it prints the contents of %flag% but then in the second prompt inside if statement, the %flag2% gets no value.

Output:

```
Enter letter 'y': y
y
Enter random string:lalala
flag2:
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem with user input in my batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/916413/problem-with-user-input-in-my-batch-file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within a block statement `(a parenthesised series of statements)`, the **entire** block is parsed and **then** executed. Any `%var%` within the block will be replaced by that variable's value **at the time the block is parsed** - before the block is executed - the same thing applies to a `FOR ... DO (block)`.

Hence, `IF (something) else (somethingelse)` will be executed using the values of `%variables%` at the time the `IF` is encountered.

Two common ways to overcome this are 1) to use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and use `!var!` in place of `%var%` to access the changed value of `var` or 2) to call a subroutine to perform further processing using the changed values.

Note therefore the use of `CALL ECHO %%var%%` which displays the changed value of `var`. `CALL ECHO %%errorlevel%%` displays, but sadly then RESETS errorlevel.

try

```
CALL echo flag2: %%flag2%%
```

Comment: It worked and I understood why this happens. Thank you for your explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add this line at the top or above the `IF` statement:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
```

Then change `%flag2%` to `!flag2!`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It worked but I will accept Magoo's answer as it is more complete, thus, more useful to other people encountering this problem.